# how can i add time within time and show to label2 the added time? c#

Tags: c#, time

[image: TimeAdded?]

is there a way add time? in the image
if i click the AddedTimeButton the label1 or the running time will add another hour and show it to label2

In the image label1 is 2:15:06 and if i click the button lets say the button can add 1 hour in the time and after i click it it will show in the label2 the added time 3:15:06.

is there a logic code for it or is it possible?

Comment: is there a logic code for it or is it possible? yes it is possible.

Comment: In C# you can use DateTime.AddHours(1) to add an hour to a DateTime variable

Comment: what can i use datetime.AddHours?

Comment: just today i got curious

Comment: Why don't you search about `DateTime.AddHours` and figure out yourself?

Comment: ok sir ill do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a high-level idea. Please change it to suit your implementation.

```
Label label1 = new Label();
Label label2 = new Label();

DateTime time = DateTime.Today;
label1.Text = time.ToString();

void OnButtonClicked()
{
     label2.Text = time.AddHours(1);
}
```

Comment: Happy coding @JhuliusDCatayoc!